# How replace value that match with a word in excel using C# .net

Tags: c#, excel, replace, find, office-interop

I'm trying to replace in Excel just a matching word but it is only replacing single value, I want to do something like this:

```
Column1
File_<number_of_file>_doc.txt
File_<number_of_file>_tec.txt
File_<number_of_file>_rac.txt
```

I'm not able to replace a word if it doesn't match, I would like to replace `<number_of_file>` with a number.

As I said is only replacing match value

```
Column1
<number_of_file>
<number_of_file>
<number_of_file>
```

what I have is this.

```
      object m = Type.Missing;

        // open excel.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        // open the workbook. 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(
            @"C:\TEST1.xlsx",
            m, false, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m);

        // get the active worksheet. (Replace this if you need to.) 
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;

        // get the used range. 
        Range r = (Range)ws.UsedRange;

        // call the replace method to replace instances. 
        bool success = (bool)r.Replace(
            "<number_of_file>",
            "488777",
            XlLookAt.xlWhole,
            XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
            true, m, m, m);

        // save and close. 
        wb.Save();
        app.Quit();
        app = null;
```

[image: That's the message that I got.]

Comment: You are using `XlLookAt.xlWhole` which means it will only replace in cases where the cell contains exactly "<number_of_file>" and nothing else. `xlPart` is likely what you want.

Comment: BTW I think you're now allowed to omit optional arguments when calling Interop methods (initially you had to provide *all* the arguments as you have, but that's no longer required)

Comment: That one worked for me @Tim Williams